# Table not refreshing properly after jQuery manipulations, in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

I made a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030043/html-table-headers-always-visible-at-top-of-window-when-viewing-a-large-table/1041566#1041566) to [another of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030043/html-table-headers-always-visible-at-top-of-window-when-viewing-a-large-table). But, after some recent changes, it's looking good in Firefox 3.6 but showing quite bad display anomalies in Google Chrome. It seems it's not refreshing/redrawing the table header row after the JavaScript code changes its position.

It's especially noticeable when the floating table header row is somewhere on the middle of the table, then you scroll up quickly: it leaves a copy of the header row on the middle of the table, and doesn't redraw the table properly.

[The online demo is located here.](http://cmcqueen1975.bitbucket.org/htmlFloatingTableHeader/tables.html)

The source code is in a [Mercurial bitbucket repository, here](http://bitbucket.org/cmcqueen1975/htmlfloatingtableheader/src/tip/tables.html).

I'd appreciate if anyone can point me towards a clean solution to making it refresh the display properly in Google Chrome.

**Update:** I'm seeing it on both Ubuntu Linux 10.04 and Windows XP, with Chrome version 5.0.375.99 beta. It seems more noticeable on Linux, but also a problem on Windows. I've just got 5.0.375.125 beta on Linux and it's still happening.

I'll track this with an [issue in BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org/cmcqueen1975/htmlfloatingtableheader/issue/2/table-floating-headers-not-refreshing-properly-in).

**Update** 26-Jan-2011: I've tested this with Chrome 9.0.597.67 beta on Ubuntu Linux 10.04, and the problem no longer seems to be apparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NEWER ANSWER:

I was able to workaround the problem on Windows by just delaying the reset by one "frame" of execution. Wrap the else condition in a setTimeout:

```
                setTimeout(function() {
                    floatingHeaderRow.css("visibility", "hidden");
                    floatingHeaderRow.css("top", "0");
                }, 1);
```

OLDER ANSWER:

I don't think the problem manifests on Chrome for Windows (which I just tried). However, it's possible that switching to position:fixed instead of position:absolute would both perform better and workaround your issue. Just use your interval to check if you would have needed to scroll and set position:fixed, else set back.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was thinking maybe `position:fixed` would make horizontal positioning more challenging--for example, handling left margins, horizontal scroll. But perhaps it wouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: I can recreate the problem on Chrome for Windows (Windows7/IE8).  However, I can only recreate the problem on the first table and not the second (thinner) table.

I also noticed that sometimes, on the first table, depending on my scrolling speed, I can get the header to only display part of one line so that the right column header reads only "table 1 col" and even then only half of that line is visible.

Comment: I've checked on Windows XP, and I'm seeing it there also. However, it's more noticeable in Linux. Also more noticeable on the first table, as Alison said.

Comment: My fix is simple, and it definitely solves it on Windows. Can you respond saying if it worked for you?

Comment: Yes that does seem to work-around the issue. On Linux, there is also some refresh issues when scrolling down on the first table, so I wrapped the entire function in the `setTimeout()`, and that fixed that too. It seems to make the scrolling a little more sluggish, but not by much. Definitely an idea worth considering further.

Comment: I've noticed the [Drupal implementation](http://drupalcode.org/viewvc/drupal/drupal/misc/tableheader.js?view=markup) uses `position:fixed` and looks good in Chrome. So I also think your older answer has merit.

Comment: Thanks; if the jerkiness/sluggishness gets to you, position: fixed is probably the better long-term solution. The browser will update the display much more frequently that way than with a javascript event handler on scroll.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is much simpeler, Chrome has problems with the fact that you have 2 's in your table header.

```
<thead>
<tr class="tableFloatingHeader" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; visibility: hidden; top: 0px; ">
    <th>table1 col header</th>
    <th>table1 col header</th>
</tr><tr class="tableFloatingHeaderOriginal">
    <th>table1 col header</th>
    <th>table1 col header</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

remove one, and your problem will be solved

Comment: If I remove it, that would defeat the point of my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030043/html-table-headers-always-visible-at-top-of-window-when-viewing-a-large-table/1041566#1041566) to my [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030043/html-table-headers-always-visible-at-top-of-window-when-viewing-a-large-table).

Comment: I still don't see why one table needs 2 header row, you can implement a jquery scroll event handler. the add the scrolling position to the header row position when scroll position > header.position