# Table header to stay fixed at the top when user scrolls it out of view with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I am trying to design an HTML table where the header will stay at the top of the page when AND ONLY when the user scrolls it out of view.  For example, the table may be 500 pixels down from the page, how do I make it so that if the user scrolls the header out of view (browser detects its no longer in the windows view somehow), it will stay put at the top?  Anyone can give me a Javascript solution to this?

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
      <th>Col3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>info</td>
      <td>info</td>
      <td>info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>info</td>
      <td>info</td>
      <td>info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>info</td>
      <td>info</td>
      <td>info</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

So in the above example, I want the `<thead>` to scroll with the page if it goes out of view.

IMPORTANT: I am **NOT** looking for a solution where the `<tbody>` will have a scrollbar (overflow:auto).

Comment: duplicate?
  
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030043

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML table headers always visible at top of window when viewing a large table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030043/html-table-headers-always-visible-at-top-of-window-when-viewing-a-large-table)

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You would do something like this by tapping into the `scroll` event handler on `window`, and using another `table` with a fixed position to show the header at the top of the page.

```js
var tableOffset = $("#table-1").offset().top;
var $header = $("#table-1 > thead").clone();
var $fixedHeader = $("#header-fixed").append($header);

$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
  var offset = $(this).scrollTop();

  if (offset >= tableOffset && $fixedHeader.is(":hidden")) {
    $fixedHeader.show();
  } else if (offset < tableOffset) {
    $fixedHeader.hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#header-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table-1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
      <th>Col3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>info</td>
      <td>info</td>
      <td>info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>info</td>
      <td>info</td>
      <td>info</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>info</td>
      <td>info</td>
      <td>info</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table id="header-fixed"></table>
```

This will show the table head when the user scrolls down far enough to hide the original table head.  It will hide again when the user has scrolled the page up far enough again.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/fj8wM/

Comment: I was thinking of this but what if the header columns' widths change based on the content?  Unless the column widths are fixed you could have your header row not line up with the content rows.  Just a thought.

Comment: In my case, the table width is set to a fixed width, so that should not be a problem.

Comment: this example doesn't work if the column headers' names are shorter than the column data values. Try changing that fiddle to have values like infoooooooo instead of info. I'm thinking some sort of hardcoded width that's set when cloning the table.

Comment: This has major limitations, least of which is when trying to use the table in a container other than `window`. http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/ has a more generally-applicable solution.

Comment: This might help anyone needing dynamic th widths, it what I wound up doing, it's a fork of @AndrewWhitaker:
http://jsfiddle.net/noahkoch/wLcjh/1/

Comment: @NoahKoch fixed header using your solution can be still not as wide as original head when original cells have padding. I improved your solution to add padding to duplicated cells. JSFiddle's fork: http://jsfiddle.net/1n23m69u/2/

Comment: if you change the data in the html, then it breaks http://jsfiddle.net/fj8wM/5590/

Comment: Great solution!  To improve the way it works on my page I added `width: 100%;` to the `#header-fixed {}` CSS rule, and changed the `>=` & `<` to `>` & `<=` in the script part.

Comment: Unfortunately this technique of relying on the scroll event is now deprecated because modern browsers have gone to "asynchronous scrolling." See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Scroll-linked_effects

Comment: @alanng but the solutions they provide (using position:sticky and some moz only css rules) are not real solutions. position:sticky doesnt work in any browser, and neither is using FF only css rules :P

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker this working fine in all browers. but when it comes to touch device such as iphone or ipad it is juddering because of it starts when scrolling stops. Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: @TharakaNilupulDharmabandu: Unfortunately not. This Q&A is over 6 years old now-- might be best to open a new question.

Comment: Cool example! But why do you use `# idName` instead of `getElementById()`?

Answer (score 121):

Pure CSS (without IE11 support):

```
table th {
    position: -webkit-sticky; // this is for all Safari (Desktop & iOS), not for Chrome
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1; // any positive value, layer order is global
    background: #fff; // any bg-color to overlap
}
```

Comment: I don't even see this working in Chrome.  The inspection tools show `-webkit-sticky` as an invalid value for `position`.

Comment: @carmenism `-webkit-sticky` is for Safari (Desktop & iOS), not for Chrome. `position: sticky` works in Chrome from version 56. You should set BOTH rules: `-webkit-sticky` and just `sticky` exactly in the same order as in my code example. Safari gets `webkit-sticky` and all other browsers overwrite it with `sticky`.

Comment: I was unable to get this to work. From a quick google it looks like `position: sticky` will not work with table elements.

Comment: applying to th worked for me:  table thead tr th{...}

Comment: Worked fine on Chrome 41, but ir didn't work on IE 11

Comment: You have to apply it to the **th** because it won't work on thead nor tr

Comment: OP asks for thead not th

Comment: Hey, is it possible with this sticky to fixed last row?

Comment: Nice solution! Worked on `tr` for me, when I was setting it on a specific tr element (parent to th elements)

Comment: I'm losing the borders.  Any trick to keep them with the great CSS of yours?

```<table id="ArchivesTable" class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-striped">
```

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=position%3A%20sticky

Comment: Thank you, this is a much better solution than the top answer!

Answer (score 50):

Well, I was trying to obtain the same effect without resorting to fixed size columns or having a fixed height for the entire table.

The solution I came up with is a hack. It consists of duplicating the entire table then hiding everything but the header, and making that have a fixed position.

#### HTML

```
<div id="table-container">
<table id="maintable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Col3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>some really long line here instead</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="bottom_anchor"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
body { height: 1000px; }
thead{
    background-color:white;
}
```

#### javascript

```
function moveScroll(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var anchor_top = $("#maintable").offset().top;
    var anchor_bottom = $("#bottom_anchor").offset().top;
    if (scroll>anchor_top && scroll<anchor_bottom) {
    clone_table = $("#clone");
    if(clone_table.length == 0){
        clone_table = $("#maintable").clone();
        clone_table.attr('id', 'clone');
        clone_table.css({position:'fixed',
                 'pointer-events': 'none',
                 top:0});
        clone_table.width($("#maintable").width());
        $("#table-container").append(clone_table);
        $("#clone").css({visibility:'hidden'});
        $("#clone thead").css({'visibility':'visible','pointer-events':'auto'});
    }
    } else {
    $("#clone").remove();
    }
}
$(window).scroll(moveScroll);
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/QHQGF/7/

Edit: updated the code so that the thead can receive pointer events(so buttons and links in the header still work). This fixes the problem reported by luhfluh and Joe M.

New jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cjKEx/

Comment: Nice example! Thank you, I'll use it. But wouldn't it perform better by clonning only <thead> and putting it into a <table> tag? You know, there may be a lot of elements in original table.

Comment: I tried that first, the problem with that is that the size of the elements in the header depend on the contents of the table. If you have a row with big content the entire column, including the header will grow. If you clone just the thead you lose that information and you don't get the desired effect. See  Yzmir Ramirez's comment on the accepted answer. This is the only way I found that works without fixed width columns. It isn't clean, I know, which is I way I said it was a hack.

Comment: Oh, I got it. This method is great because it works with fluid columns, I googled a little and couldn't find another one with that functionality. Anywhay, if i'll get it done somehow, I'll mention it here

Comment: I tried to use this, and it's sort of working, but it's sticking a few pixels lower from the top, and also a few pixels to the left (I can see a few pixels of the table on top and to the right of the floating header). Any idea why?

Comment: I also noticed that the buttons I had on the header do not work when it is floating.

Comment: Can you put your example on jsfiddle or something like that? Maybe I can help with debugging.

Comment: Hi @entropy, Im having similar problem as "Joe M... Currently No element or member with ID named 'clone' is part of table or div container in your HTML example shown above, yet the JS script has line  `clone_table = $("#clone");`...could this be one reason why buttons and/or other elements which are part of the header dont get their functionality working on the clone even though they appear on the 'cloned header'?

Comment: @luhfluh, can you put up an example on jsfiddle or something similar so I can see what you're talking about? I asked Joe M. for that but he didn't reply

Comment: @Entropy, here is my jsfiddle example which shows links (possibly for sorting) and other elements (buttons, submits, menu related, etc) does not work with your jquery example solution... [http://jsfiddle.net/luhfluh/KX2AG/4/] I read somewhere that jquery `.clone()` does not deepcopy elements and its sub children data...could that be a reason?  I tried playing around with `.clone(true,true)` which should be able to deepcopy ..but results same as previous...any suggestions appreciated! ..tks

Comment: @luhfluh, yeah, the problem was due to the pointer-events:none in the cloned table. This is used so that clicks go through the clone and to the original table. Reverting it in the header of the cloned table so that the header(and only the header) is clickable fixes the problem. I've updated my post to reflect this :)

Comment: problem adding border on <thead><th>

Comment: This solutions worked for me, one small problem is if the table extends to the right past the screen. If the user scrolls right, the header does not scroll. Otherwise good.

Comment: @JamVille Because cloned table has `visibility: hidden`. You can hide only `#clone tbody` and after that you can set border... Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QHQGF/1707/

Comment: @kurdtpage - fixed the issue where scrolling horizontally led to the column headers no longer aligning with the table body. I have a fiddle for it, but the fiddle website doesn't give you a horizontal scroll bar with which to test. In any case, the changes are all in the js. http://jsfiddle.net/cgkxeqt5/

Answer (score 33):

I wrote a plugin that does this. Ive been working on it for about a year now and I think it handles all the corner cases pretty well:

- scrolling within a container with overflow
- scrolling within a window
- taking care of what happens when you resize the window
- keeping your events bound to the header
- **most importantly it doesn't force you to change your table's css** to make it work

Here are some demos/docs:
http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/

Comment: looks nice but will not work if the table already runs other plugins (like in my case) wich conflict with the strict rules of your plugin

Comment: it works with any plugin that caches its selectors, which what good plugins should do. But no one does this any more because the young'ins never had to write any jquery plugins for IE6.

Comment: Works great, also good to mention is that it works very well with multidimensional tables! Only thing to point out is that when you call it to fast the table width get's a bit messed up. But that's easy to avoid with some callbacks.

Comment: This is awesome, saved me a lot of time, thank you!

Comment: I am surprised that people still use this, but they do use it. I just cut a new minor version this week to fix some bug from 2015 that someone re-discovered.

Answer (score 27):

I was able to fix the problem with changing column widths.  I started with Andrew's solution above (thanks so much!) and then added one little loop to set the widths of the cloned td's:

```
$("#header-fixed td").each(function(index){
    var index2 = index;
    $(this).width(function(index2){
        return $("#table-1 td").eq(index).width();
    });
});
```

This solves the problem without having to clone the entire table and hide the body.  I'm brand new to JavaScript and jQuery (and to stack overflow), so any comments are appreciated.

Comment: Worked well but I needed to add following line
$("#header-fixed").width($("#table-1").width());
for columns to line up correctly.

Answer (score 21):

There are many really good solution here already. But one of the simplest CSS only solutions that I use in these situations is as follows:

```css
table {
  /* Not required only for visualizing */
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

table thead tr th {
  /* Important */
  background-color: red;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
}

td {
  /* Not required only for visualizing */
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
      <th>Col3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Because there is no requirement for JavaScript it simplifies the situation significantly. You essentially need to focus on the *second* CSS rule, which contains the conditions for ensuring that the head of the table remains of the top no matter the scroll space.

To elaborate on each of the rules in detail. `position` is meant to indicate to the browser that the head object, its row, and its cells all need to stick to the top. This necessarily needs to be accompanied by `top`, which specifies to the browser that the head will stick to the top of the page or viewport. Additionally, you can add `z-index` to ensure that the content of the head always remains on the top.

The background colour is merely to illustrate the point. You do not need to use any additional JavaScript to get this effect. This is supported in most major browsers after 2016.

Comment: simple and clean! this saved my hours

Answer (score 17):

This is by far the best solution I've found for having a fixed table header.

UPDATE 5/11: Fixed horizontal scrolling bug as pointed out by [Kerry Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque/22996338?noredirect=1#comment87494121_22996338)

Codepen: https://codepen.io/josephting/pen/demELL

```js
;(function($) {
   $.fn.fixMe = function() {
      return this.each(function() {
         var $this = $(this),
            $t_fixed;
         function init() {
            $this.wrap('<div class="container" />');
            $t_fixed = $this.clone();
            $t_fixed.find("tbody").remove().end().addClass("fixed").insertBefore($this);
            resizeFixed();
         }
         function resizeFixed() {
           $t_fixed.width($this.outerWidth());
            $t_fixed.find("th").each(function(index) {
               $(this).css("width",$this.find("th").eq(index).outerWidth()+"px");
            });
         }
         function scrollFixed() {
            var offsetY = $(this).scrollTop(),
            offsetX = $(this).scrollLeft(),
            tableOffsetTop = $this.offset().top,
            tableOffsetBottom = tableOffsetTop + $this.height() - $this.find("thead").height(),
            tableOffsetLeft = $this.offset().left;
            if(offsetY < tableOffsetTop || offsetY > tableOffsetBottom)
               $t_fixed.hide();
            else if(offsetY >= tableOffsetTop && offsetY <= tableOffsetBottom && $t_fixed.is(":hidden"))
               $t_fixed.show();
            $t_fixed.css("left", tableOffsetLeft - offsetX + "px");
         }
         $(window).resize(resizeFixed);
         $(window).scroll(scrollFixed);
         init();
      });
   };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("table").fixMe();
   $(".up").click(function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
   }, 2000);
 });
});
```

```css
body{
  font:1.2em normal Arial,sans-serif;
  color:#34495E;
}

h1{
  text-align:center;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  letter-spacing:-2px;
  font-size:2.5em;
  margin:20px 0;
}

.container{
  width:90%;
  margin:auto;
}

table{
  border-collapse:collapse;
  width:100%;
}

.blue{
  border:2px solid #1ABC9C;
}

.blue thead{
  background:#1ABC9C;
}

.purple{
  border:2px solid #9B59B6;
}

.purple thead{
  background:#9B59B6;
}

thead{
  color:white;
}

th,td{
  text-align:center;
  padding:5px 0;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even){
  background:#ECF0F1;
}

tbody tr:hover{
background:#BDC3C7;
  color:#FFFFFF;
}

.fixed{
  top:0;
  position:fixed;
  width:auto;
  display:none;
  border:none;
}

.scrollMore{
  margin-top:600px;
}

.up{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>&darr; SCROLL &darr;</h1>
<table class="blue">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Colonne 1</th>
      <th>Colonne 2</th>
      <th>Colonne 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>MaisMaisMaisMaisMaisMaisMaisMaisMaisMaisMaisMaisMaisMaisMaisMaisMaisMaisMaisMais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h1 class="scrollMore">&darr; SCROLL MORE &darr;</h1>
<table class="purple">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Colonne 1</th>
      <th>Colonne 2</th>
      <th>Colonne 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
      <td>Non</td>
      <td>Mais</td>
      <td>Allo !</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<h1 class="up scrollMore">&uarr; UP &uarr;</h1>
```

Comment: I fixed this script so that it can handle <th> elements that have border and padding (otherwise it sets the fixed header <th> widths too wide). Simply change `outerWidth` to `width` in the resizeFixed() function definition.

Comment: You may also need to add a CSS property of `z-index` to some positive number on the `.fixed` class so that objects rendered post-pageload in the table don't float on top of the fixed header as you scroll.

Comment: how to dynamically handle the top position. Let say, I need to scroll upto below my main page fixed header content. **.fixed{
  top:0;}**.

Comment: @VVijay You can always adjust the positioning of the fixed header. The idea here is to show the fixed copy of the table header when your page get scrolled to the point you set it to be. See `scrollFixed()` function.

Comment: Yes. I can able to show the fixed copy of the table header when the required point. But, It was always show at the top because of *.fixed {top:0;}*. In one page, I need to show the header at *Top:0;* in another page at *top:30px;*

Comment: @VVijay In that case, you just have to add additional rules to specify `top:0px;` and `top:30px;` which is basic CSS and HTML.

Comment: Almost there, but doesn't handle horizontal scrolling and dynamic column data widths.  Resize window down at  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ryxyvm and see how it breaks.  For very simple tables with equal column widths it may be a good solution, otherwise it would be considered buggy.

Comment: @KerryJohnson Thanks for the note. I've made some changes so it supports horizontal scrolling and dynamic column widths.

Answer (score 8):

I found a simple solution without using **JQuery** and using **CSS** only.

You have to put the fixed contents inside  'th' tags and add the CSS

```
table th {
    position:sticky;
    top:0;
    z-index:1;
    border-top:0;
    background: #ededed;
}
```

The position, z-index and top properties are enough. But you can apply the rest to give for a better view.

Comment: How is this different from [Ihor Zenich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque/43786376#43786376), which was posted two years earlier?

Answer (score 7):

Best solution is to use this jquery plugin:

https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders

This plugin worked great for us and we tried a lot other solutions. We tested it in IE, Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Do you know any solution which also preserves the functionality of knockout data bound controls in the header?

Comment: Didn't work for me: headers are outside of table and stick to top of the browser (window), even with the option "scrollableArea".  I saw that this was mentioned before without additional comments. Maybe it needs a CSS that he use and is not available to make it work.

Answer (score 5):

I found a simple jQuery library called Sticky Table Headers.  Two lines of code and it did exactly what I wanted.  The solutions above don't manage the column widths, so if you have table cells that take up a lot of space, the resulting size of the persistent header will not match your table's width.

http://plugins.jquery.com/StickyTableHeaders/

Usage info here:
https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders

Answer (score 3):

you can use this approach, pure HTML and CSS no JS needed :)

```css
.table-fixed-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-right: 18px
}

.table-fixed {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.column {
  flex-basis: 24%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.column .title {
  border-bottom: 2px grey solid;
  border-top: 2px grey solid;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.cell {
  padding: 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  border-left: 1px solid;
}

.cell:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Fixed header Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="table-fixed-header">
    
    <div class="column">
      <span class="title">col 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <span class="title">col 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <span class="title">col 3</span>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <span class="title">col 4</span>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  
  <div class="table-fixed">
    
    <div class="column">
      <div class="cell">alpha</div>
      <div class="cell">beta</div>
      <div class="cell">ceta</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
      <div class="cell">alpha</div>
      <div class="cell">beta</div>
      <div class="cell">ceta</div>
      <div class="cell">alpha</div>
      <div class="cell">beta</div>
      <div class="cell">ceta</div>
      <div class="cell">alpha</div>
      <div class="cell">beta</div>
      <div class="cell">ceta</div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
      <div class="cell">alpha</div>
      <div class="cell">beta</div>
      <div class="cell">ceta</div>
      <div class="cell">beta</div>
      <div class="cell">beta</div>
      <div class="cell">beta</div>
      
    </div>
    
    <div class="column">
      <div class="cell">alpha</div>
      <div class="cell">beta</div>
      <div class="cell">ceta</div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Below Code Working Perfect, Try!

```html
<style>
table th {
  background-color:gray;
  color:#fff;
}
table td {
  text-align:center;
  color:#000;
}
</style>
<table style='width:100%;'>
<tr style="position: -webkit-sticky; position: sticky; top: 0;">
  <th>Hour</th>
  <th>Start</th>
  <th>End</th>
  <th>Pcs</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>555</td>
  <td>666</td>
  <td>777</td>
  <td>888</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>999</td>
  <td>1010</td>
  <td>1212</td>
  <td>1414</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1515</td>
  <td>1616</td>
  <td>1717</td>
  <td>1818</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>111</td>
  <td>222</td>
  <td>333</td>
  <td>444</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

I too experienced the same issues with the border formatting not being shown using entrophy's code but a few little fixes and now the table is expandable and displays all css styling rules you may add.

to css add:

```
#maintable{width: 100%}
```

then here is the new javascript:

```
    function moveScroll(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var anchor_top = $("#maintable").offset().top;
    var anchor_bottom = $("#bottom_anchor").offset().top;
    if (scroll > anchor_top && scroll < anchor_bottom) {
        clone_table = $("#clone");
        if(clone_table.length === 0) {          
            clone_table = $("#maintable").clone();
            clone_table.attr({id: "clone"})
            .css({
                position: "fixed",
                "pointer-events": "none",
                 top:0
            })
            .width($("#maintable").width());

            $("#table-container").append(clone_table);
            // dont hide the whole table or you lose border style & 
            // actively match the inline width to the #maintable width if the 
            // container holding the table (window, iframe, div) changes width          
            $("#clone").width($("#maintable").width());
            // only the clone thead remains visible
            $("#clone thead").css({
                visibility:"visible"
            });
            // clone tbody is hidden
            $("#clone tbody").css({
                visibility:"hidden"
            });
            // add support for a tfoot element
            // and hide its cloned version too
            var footEl = $("#clone tfoot");
            if(footEl.length){
                footEl.css({
                    visibility:"hidden"
                });
            }
        }
    } 
    else {
        $("#clone").remove();
    }
}
$(window).scroll(moveScroll);
```

Comment: This does work better than entropy's solution as far as border formatting goes in the header. However, in current Firefox (but not Chrome) it creates visible cell-border artifacts below the table once scrolling starts.

Comment: This solution works. But when the windows is small, it the cloned header doesn't scroll horizontally, any suggestion to fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that builds upon the accepted answer.  It corrects for: column widths, matching table style, and when the table is scrolled in a container div.

**Usage**

Ensure your table has a `<thead>` tag because only thead content will be fixed.

```
$("#header-fixed").fixHeader();
```

**JavaSript**

```
//Custom JQuery Plugin
(function ($) {
    $.fn.fixHeader = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $table = $(this);
            var $sp = $table.scrollParent();
            var tableOffset = $table.position().top;
            var $tableFixed = $("<table />")
                .prop('class', $table.prop('class'))
                .css({ position: "fixed", "table-layout": "fixed", display: "none", "margin-top": "0px" });
            $table.before($tableFixed);
            $tableFixed.append($table.find("thead").clone());

            $sp.bind("scroll", function () {
                var offset = $(this).scrollTop();

                if (offset > tableOffset && $tableFixed.is(":hidden")) {
                    $tableFixed.show();
                    var p = $table.position();
                    var offset = $sp.offset();

                    //Set the left and width to match the source table and the top to match the scroll parent
                    $tableFixed.css({ left: p.left + "px", top: (offset ? offset.top : 0) + "px", }).width($table.width());

                    //Set the width of each column to match the source table
                    $.each($table.find('th, td'), function (i, th) {
                        $($tableFixed.find('th, td')[i]).width($(th).width());
                    });

                }
                else if (offset <= tableOffset && !$tableFixed.is(":hidden")) {
                    $tableFixed.hide();
                }
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This worked well for me.  Only thing is an issue with tables that need to scroll horizontally.  I've made an update in a JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/4mgneob1/1/  I subtract `$sp.scrollLeft()` which gets the amount scrolled from left so when scrolling down the fixed table is positioned correctly.  Also added check when scrolling horizontally if fixed table is visible to adjust left position.  Another issue I couldn't solve is when the table goes above the viewport the fixed table should hide until the user scrolls back up.

Comment: Getting `Uncaught TypeError: $table.scrollParent is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

This will help you to have a fixed header which can also be scrolled horizontally with data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Shubh</title>



<script type="text/javascript">
    var lastSeen = [ 0, 0 ];
    function checkScroll(div1, div2) {
        if (!div1 || !div2)
            return;
        var control = null;
        if (div1.scrollLeft != lastSeen[0])
            control = div1;
        else if (div2.scrollLeft != lastSeen[1])
            control = div2;
        if (control == null)
            return;
        else
            div1.scrollLeft = div2.scrollLeft = control.scrollLeft;
        lastSeen[0] = div1.scrollLeft;
        lastSeen[1] = div2.scrollLeft;
    }

    window
            .setInterval(
                    "checkScroll(document.getElementById('innertablediv'), document.getElementById('headertable'))",
                    1);
</script>

<style type="text/css">
#full {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}

#innertablediv {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#headertable {
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="full">




        <div id="headertable">
            <table border="1" bgcolor="grey" width="150px" id="headertable">
                <tr>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>

                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>




        <div id="innertablediv">

            <table border="1" id="innertableid">
                <tr>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                    <td>shubh, ansh</td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will help you to have a fixed header which can also be scrolled horizontally with data.

Answer (score 1):

```
function fix_table_header_position(){
 var width_list = [];
 $("th").each(function(){
    width_list.push($(this).width());
 });
 $("tr:first").css("position", "absolute");
 $("tr:first").css("z-index", "1000");
 $("th, td").each(function(index){
    $(this).width(width_list[index]);
 });

 $("tr:first").after("<tr height=" + $("tr:first").height() + "></tr>");}
```

This is my solution

Answer (score 1):

In this  solution fixed header is created dynamically, 
the content and style is cloned from THEAD

all you need is two lines for example:

`var $myfixedHeader = $("#Ttodo").FixedHeader(); //create fixed header
$(window).scroll($myfixedHeader.moveScroll);    //bind function to scroll event`

My jquery plugin FixedHeader and 
getStyleObject provided below you can to put in the file .js

```js
// JAVASCRIPT



/*
 * getStyleObject Plugin for jQuery JavaScript Library
 * From: http://upshots.org/?p=112
 
Basic usage:
$.fn.copyCSS = function(source){
  var styles = $(source).getStyleObject();
  this.css(styles);
}
*/

(function($){
    $.fn.getStyleObject = function(){
        var dom = this.get(0);
        var style;
        var returns = {};
        if(window.getComputedStyle){
            var camelize = function(a,b){
                return b.toUpperCase();
            };
            style = window.getComputedStyle(dom, null);
            for(var i = 0, l = style.length; i < l; i++){
                var prop = style[i];
                var camel = prop.replace(/\-([a-z])/g, camelize);
                var val = style.getPropertyValue(prop);
                returns[camel] = val;
            };
            return returns;
        };
        if(style = dom.currentStyle){
            for(var prop in style){
                returns[prop] = style[prop];
            };
            return returns;
        };
        return this.css();
    }
})(jQuery);



   
//Floating Header of long table  PiotrC
(function ( $ ) {
    var tableTop,tableBottom,ClnH;
    $.fn.FixedHeader = function(){
        tableTop=this.offset().top,
        tableBottom=this.outerHeight()+tableTop;
        //Add Fixed header
        this.after('<table id="fixH"></table>');
        //Clone Header
        ClnH=$("#fixH").html(this.find("thead").clone());
        //set style
        ClnH.css({'position':'fixed', 'top':'0', 'zIndex':'60', 'display':'none',
        'border-collapse': this.css('border-collapse'),
  'border-spacing': this.css('border-spacing'),
        'margin-left': this.css('margin-left'),
        'width': this.css('width')            
        });
        //rewrite style cell of header
        $.each(this.find("thead>tr>th"), function(ind,val){
            $(ClnH.find('tr>th')[ind]).css($(val).getStyleObject());
        });
    return ClnH;}
    
    $.fn.moveScroll=function(){
        var offset = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (offset > tableTop && offset<tableBottom){
            if(ClnH.is(":hidden"))ClnH.show();
            $("#fixH").css('margin-left',"-"+$(window).scrollLeft()+"px");
        }
        else if (offset < tableTop || offset>tableBottom){
            if(!ClnH.is(':hidden'))ClnH.hide();
        }
    };
})( jQuery );





var $myfixedHeader = $("#repTb").FixedHeader();
$(window).scroll($myfixedHeader.moveScroll);
```

```css
/* CSS - important only NOT transparent background */

#repTB{border-collapse: separate;border-spacing: 0;}

#repTb thead,#fixH thead{background: #e0e0e0 linear-gradient(#d8d8d8 0%, #e0e0e0 25%, #e0e0e0 75%, #d8d8d8 100%) repeat scroll 0 0;border:1px solid #CCCCCC;}

#repTb td{border:1px solid black}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<h3>example</h3> 
<table id="repTb">
<thead>
<tr><th>Col1</th><th>Column2</th><th>Description</th></tr>
</thead>
<tr><td>info</td><td>info</td><td>info</td></tr>
<tr><td>info</td><td>info</td><td>info</td></tr>
<tr><td>info</td><td>info</td><td>info</td></tr>
<tr><td>info</td><td>info</td><td>info</td></tr>
<tr><td>info</td><td>info</td><td>info</td></tr>
<tr><td>info</td><td>info</td><td>info</td></tr>
<tr><td>info</td><td>info</td><td>info</td></tr>
<tr><td>info</td><td>info</td><td>info</td></tr>
<tr><td>info</td><td>info</td><td>info</td></tr>
<tr><td>info</td><td>info</td><td>info</td></tr>
<tr><td>info</td><td>info</td><td>info</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but here is an implementation that works with multiple tables on the same page and "jank" free (using requestAnimationFrame). Also there's no need to provide any width on the columns. Horizontal scrolling works as well.

The headers are defined in a `div` so you are free to add any markup there (like buttons), if required. This is all the HTML that is needed:

```
<div class="tbl-resp">
  <table id="tbl1" class="tbl-resp__tbl">
     <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>col 1</th>
        <th>col 2</th>
        <th>col 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead> 
  </table>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lloydleo/bk5pt5gs/

Answer (score 1):

Create extra table with same header as the main table. Just put thead in the new table with one row and all the headers in it. Do position absolute and background white. For main table put it in a div and use some height and overflow-y scroll. This way our new table will overcome the header of main table and stay there. Surround everything in a div. Below is the rough code to do it.

```
      <div class="col-sm-8">

        <table id="header-fixed" class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width: 351px;position: absolute;background: white;">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Col3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
      </table>


    <div style="height: 300px;overflow-y: scroll;">
          <table id="tableMain" class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="table-layout:fixed;overflow-wrap: break-word;cursor:pointer">
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
      <th>Col3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>

                                    </table>
              </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
div.wrapper {
    padding:20px;
}
table.scroll thead {
    width: 100%;
    background: #FC6822;
}
table.scroll thead tr:after {
    content: '';
    overflow-y: scroll;
    visibility: hidden;
}
table.scroll thead th {
    flex: 1 auto;
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}
table.scroll tbody {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 200px;
}
table.scroll thead tr,
table.scroll tbody tr {
    display: flex;
}
table.scroll tbody tr td {
    flex: 1 auto;
    word-wrap: break;
}
table.scroll thead tr th,
table.scroll tbody tr td {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align-left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="scroll">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Vorname</th>
                <th>Beruf</th>
                <th>Alter</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Müller</td>
                <td>Marie</td>
                <td>Künstlerin</td>
                <td>26</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Meier</td>
                <td>Stefan</td>
                <td>Chemiker</td>
                <td>52</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Schmidt</td>
                <td>Sabrine</td>
                <td>Studentin</td>
                <td>38</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mustermann</td>
                <td>Max</td>
                <td>Lehrer</td>
                <td>41</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Müller</td>
                <td>Marie</td>
                <td>Künstlerin</td>
                <td>26</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Meier</td>
                <td>Stefan</td>
                <td>Chemiker</td>
                <td>52</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Schmidt</td>
                <td>Sabrine</td>
                <td>Studentin</td>
                <td>38</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mustermann</td>
                <td>Max</td>
                <td>Lehrer</td>
                <td>41</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Müller</td>
                <td>Marie</td>
                <td>Künstlerin</td>
                <td>26</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Meier</td>
                <td>Stefan</td>
                <td>Chemiker</td>
                <td>52</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Schmidt</td>
                <td>Sabrine</td>
                <td>Studentin</td>
                <td>38</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mustermann</td>
                <td>Max</td>
                <td>Lehrer</td>
                <td>41</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Demo:** [css fixed table header demo](https://www.revilodesign.de/blog/css-tricks/css-table-header-fixed-thead-einer-tabelle-fixieren/)

Answer (score 1):

Fix your issue with this

```
tbody {
  display: table-caption;
  height: 200px;
  caption-side: bottom;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

solution in my case, i have use only css for this:

first we nee table format like this :

```
<table>
<thead><tr><th></th></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><td></td><tr></tbody>
</table>
```

And apply this css :

```
tbody {
    display:block;
    max-height:280px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    }
    thead, tbody tr {
        display:table;
        width:100%;
        table-layout:fixed;
    }
```

and header is fixed

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using style property transform.
All you have to do is wrapping your table into some div with fixed height and overflow set to auto, for example:

```
.tableWrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  height: calc( 100% - 10rem );
}
```

And then you can attach onscroll handler to it, here you have method that finds each table wrapped with `<div class="tableWrapper"></div>`:

```
  fixTables () {
    document.querySelectorAll('.tableWrapper').forEach((tableWrapper) => {
      tableWrapper.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        var translate = 'translate(0,' + tableWrapper.scrollTop + 'px)'
        tableWrapper.querySelector('thead').style.transform = translate
      })
    })
  }
```

And here is working example of this in action (i have used bootstrap to make it prettier): [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/budyniowski/7edk82o4/)

For those who also want to support IE and Edge, here is the snippet:

```
  fixTables () {
    const tableWrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.tableWrapper')
    for (let i = 0, len = tableWrappers.length; i < len; i++) {
      tableWrappers[i].addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        const translate = 'translate(0,' + tableWrappers[i].scrollTop + 'px)'
        const headers = tableWrappers[i].querySelectorAll('thead th')
        for (let i = 0, len = headers.length; i < len; i++) {
          headers[i].style.transform = translate
        }
      })
    }
  }
```

In IE and Edge scroll is a little bit laggy... but it works

Here is answer which helps me to find out this: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25902860/6474767)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried most of these solutions, and eventually found (IMO) the best, modern, solution:

### CSS grids

---

With CSS grids, you can define a 'grid', and you can *finally* create a nice, javascript-free, cross-browser solution for a table with a fixed header, and scrollable content. The header height can even dynamic.

**CSS**: Display as grid, and set the number of `template-rows`:

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 50px auto; // For fixed height header
    grid-template-rows: auto auto; // For dynamic height header
}
```

**HTML**: Create a grid container and the number of defined `rows`:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

---

Here is working example:

**CSS**

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px auto;
}
.table-heading {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.table-content {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="table">
            <div class="table-heading">
                HEADING
            </div>
            <div class="table-content">
                CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT <br/>
                CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT <br/>
                CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT <br/>
                CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT <br/>
                CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT <br/>
                CONTENT - CONTENT - CONTENT <br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it using **transformation:translate**. While it works good in Firefox and Chrome, there is simply no function in IE11. No double scroll bars. Supports table tfoot and caption. Pure Javascript, no jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/wbLqzrfb/42/

```
thead.style.transform="translate(0,"+(dY-top-1)+"px)";
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution without jquery

HTML

```
<table class="fixed_header">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
      <th>Col 5</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>row 1-0</td>
      <td>row 1-1</td>
      <td>row 1-2</td>
      <td>row 1-3</td>
      <td>row 1-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 2-0</td>
      <td>row 2-1</td>
      <td>row 2-2</td>
      <td>row 2-3</td>
      <td>row 2-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 3-0</td>
      <td>row 3-1</td>
      <td>row 3-2</td>
      <td>row 3-3</td>
      <td>row 3-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 4-0</td>
      <td>row 4-1</td>
      <td>row 4-2</td>
      <td>row 4-3</td>
      <td>row 4-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 5-0</td>
      <td>row 5-1</td>
      <td>row 5-2</td>
      <td>row 5-3</td>
      <td>row 5-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 6-0</td>
      <td>row 6-1</td>
      <td>row 6-2</td>
      <td>row 6-3</td>
      <td>row 6-4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>row 7-0</td>
      <td>row 7-1</td>
      <td>row 7-2</td>
      <td>row 7-3</td>
      <td>row 7-4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.fixed_header{
    width: 400px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.fixed_header tbody{
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.fixed_header thead tr {
   display: block;
}

.fixed_header thead {
  background: black;
  color:#fff;
}

.fixed_header th, .fixed_header td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
}
```

You can see it working here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/lexsoul/fqbsty3h

Source: https://medium.com/@vembarrajan/html-css-tricks-scroll-able-table-body-tbody-d23182ae0fbc

Answer (score 0):

Most simple CSS, this will work single and multi rows of table headers too

```
 /* CSS */

.fix-head-table thead { 
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.fix-head-table thead th{ 
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0.5px rgb(192 192 192);
    border: none;
}
```

You can modify box-shadow inset "0.5px" shadow spread value in developer window css(inspect element) as your need and also color of that

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

```css
  .table-container {
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  table thead {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
 <div class="table-container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Phone</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>john@gmail.com</td>
        <td>0123456789</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>john@gmail.com</td>
        <td>0123456789</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>john@gmail.com</td>
        <td>0123456789</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>john@gmail.com</td>
        <td>0123456789</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>john@gmail.com</td>
        <td>0123456789</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>john@gmail.com</td>
        <td>0123456789</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>john@gmail.com</td>
        <td>0123456789</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>john@gmail.com</td>
        <td>0123456789</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>john@gmail.com</td>
        <td>0123456789</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>john@gmail.com</td>
        <td>0123456789</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>john@gmail.com</td>
        <td>0123456789</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**update 2024**, remove any style you have in the `thead` tag and give those style to the tr inside `thead` to make the code below work:

```
.table-responsive thead > tr {
  display: table-row; /* Revert to default display value */
  position: sticky; /* Fix the position of the table header */
  top: 0; /* Position it at the top of the container */
  z-index: 999; /* Ensure it's above other content */
}
```