# Datatable fixed characters in Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, datatables

How can i fixed number of character in a row then shwoing three dot **(Like "some text...")**

Example :

```
|Name          |   Age   |Description    |
+-------+---------+----------------------+
|Alice         | 34      | abcderh zyz...|
+-------+---------+----------------------+ 
|Robert La...  | 34      | Sometext is...|
```

If you able to analyze `"Sometext is..."` and after `is/La` it is showing three dots instead of full character/String.
how can do it for single as well all column.

I have try a lot on Google but still not able to find any helpful tutorials over this problem.

my Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
} );
```

I have tried all these link:

[jQuery DataTable overflow and text-wrapping issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058109/jquery-datatable-overflow-and-text-wrapping-issues)

[jQuery DataTables issue: columns and rows not in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426523/jquery-datatables-issue-columns-and-rows-not-in-one-line)

but all it did't go through my problem. please help me guys.

Answer (score 2):

You need `text-overflow: ellipsis;` or `text-overflow: "...";` to be set in your **`css`**:

```
td{
  text-overflow: ellipsis; // this is producing "..."
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or more contextual:

```
#example td{
  text-overflow: ellipsis; // this is producing "..."
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

#### [Docs for text-overflow @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

Comment: _CSS_ is always a better way to go than _JavaScript_ when such a simple solution is available

Comment: @PaulS absolutely correct!...i love to try using less js as possible.

Comment: thanks for Your answer, but it will not producing "..."

Comment: It will turn all row into single column but still "..." is missing how can i decide width of column then after it will gives me "...".

Comment: Then you can use this: `text-overflow: "...";`