# How keep table header positions fixed with vertical scroll and horizontal scroll in a html page

Tags: css-position, tableheader

How could keep the table headr position fixed, when I scroll the html with horizontal or vertical scroll?
Thanks a lot.

Example Page: http://para.maximintegrated.com/en/search.mvp?fam=stepdn&270=Internal%20Pwr.%20FETs&tree=powersupplies

[My Failed Case](http://ppt.cc/yagx)

Comment: here we go - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque

Answer (score 0):

This question was raised already by some other. Just go through these links hope u will get what you are trying to look for.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983031/jquery-how-to-freeze-table-header-and-allow-scrolling-of-the-rest-of-the-rows?