# How can I simply freeze the first row of my table using pure Javascript, no plugins?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, tableheader

I only need this table to work in the latest version of Google Chrome (so no need to worry about cross-browser solutions, like older versions of IE, etc.)

I am looking for a solution to freeze the first row and not having any success. If I exclude the word `relative` in this CSS `position: fixed relative;` then the header rows stack on top of each other. Not sure how to get the header to stay at the top of the screen when I scroll.

### Code for the Table

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#status_report .measure[data-bg='1']").css('background', 'red');
    $( "#status_report .measure[data-bg='2']").css('background', 'grey');
    $( "#status_report .measure[data-bg='3']").css('background', 'yellow');
    $( "#status_report .measure[data-bg='4']").css('background', 'green');
});

</script>
<style type="text/css">
th{
    position: fixed relative;
    background:#111;
    color:#fff;
    padding: 2px;
}
td
{
    background:#ddd;
    max-width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 2px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="status_report">
<tr>
    <th>field1</th>
    <th>field2</th>
    <th>field3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php foreach( $data as $row ) : ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['field1']; ?></td>
    <td class = "measure" data-bg="<?php echo $row['field2']; ?>"><?php echo $row['field2']; ?></td>    
    <td class = "measure" data-bg="<?php echo $row['field3']; ?>"><?php echo $row['field3']; ?></td>        
</tr>
<? endforeach;
$dbh = null; ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque I think. jQuery isn't what I thought you meant by "pure javascript no plugins" but you seem to be using it already.

Comment: @MMM by "freeze" I mean persist on the screen and not disapear from screen when I scroll the table

Comment: @drquicksilver good point re: jquery, already not using a "pure" js solution. jquery solution would be fine.

Comment: That's simply `position: fixed` :) You can't do `position: fixed relative`, what's that suppose to be?

Comment: @MMM as you say, `position: fixed` causes them to stack so I will try to use absolute position along with the `fixed` attribute. Thanks! and `position: fixed relative` is garbage! haha just worked when I typed it in and wasn't sure why. Just learning here. Thanks for other link below too. Cheers

Comment: "I will try to use absolute position along with the fixed attribute." - You can't use two values for `position`, that doesn't make any sense. It's like saying that something is both north and south :)

Comment: @MMM makes sense. You can tell I'm a rookie! I just did as you suggested with two containers (and two separate tables) but now the columns don't line up right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position: fixed relative` is invalid CSS. When you set something to be `fixed`, its position "resets", as in, the object will not stay "where it's suppose to be" and will became relative to the document, so you need to set it's position using `top`, `left` etc.

That's why they stack.

[Read more about positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/).

Comment: you seem to know your CSS. What is your prefered method to "freeze" the top row of a table?

Comment: Does it really need to be a row? It can't be a div? De-attaching the row from the table is quite risky, it would be a lot safer to render the content in a separate div and make that fixed. However if you really need to do that, you would have to offset the rest of the table by using a margin, so that the rows don't stack on top of each other. However I highly recommend to use a separate container for your fixed content.

Comment: Well I'm not exactly sure why you want to make the first row fixed - what will be the purpose of that row?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a JScrollpane for that.

But if the user is out of the focus of the JScrollPane it will not work. 
So you could catch the onscroll event if the user is outside the JScrollPane and reset the position.

Here is an example of this:

http://christian-illies.info/2011/11/javascript-scrollbalken-mit-jscrollpane/