# Fixed table headers with a fixed banner div

Tags: jquery, css, fixed-header-tables

I have used code from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque) to successfully create fixed table headers, however I'm having a few issues adapting it to my page that I can't figure out. I'm a little new to Javascript/jQuery so please bear with me a little.

The code relies on the scroll event in the browser to detect when the 
**THEAD** is out of view so that it knows when to clone the table and position the cloned header at the top of the page.
However my page has a **DIV** fixed at the top of the page that contains a search bar etc and when this is present the fixed header does not work. I'm struggling to find a way around this as I need the fixed area. It's probably really simple but I'm not seeing it.

The code snippet is as follows:

```
function moveScroll() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var anchor_top = $("#maintable").offset().top;
    var anchor_bottom = $("#bottom_anchor").offset().top;

    if (scroll > anchor_top && scroll < anchor_bottom) {
        clone_table = $("#clone");

        if (clone_table.length === 0) {
            clone_table = $("#maintable").clone();
            clone_table.attr({
                id: "clone"
            }).css({
                position: "fixed",
                "pointer-events": "none",
                top: 0
            }).width($("#maintable").width());

            $("#table-container").append(clone_table);

            $("#clone").width($("#maintable").width());

            $("#clone").css({
                border: "none"
            });

            $("#clone thead").css({
                visibility: "true"
            });

            $("#clone tbody").css({
                visibility: "hidden"
            });

            var footEl = $("#clone tfoot");
            if (footEl.length) {
                footEl.css({
                visibility: "hidden"
            });
        }
    }
    } else {
        $("#clone").remove();
    }
}

$(window).scroll(moveScroll);
```

Here's a JSFiddle with a stripped down version of the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/urvfE/

If you remove the CSS sections for `#topsection` and `#table-container` you'll see the fixed headers in action. When these sections are present nothing works.

As an aside, I also have one other issue. If I use `border-collapse:collapse` on the table to get nice borders Firefox doesn't render the fixed header properly. It renders a full empty table over the top instead. Any ideas how to circumvent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came back to this problem after the weekend and solved it. I can't believe I couldn't see this last week! It proves what a fresh pair of eyes can do.
I thought I'd answer it here in case anyone else would like this code.

I changed one of the variables to listen to the top of the main section instead of the whole window:

```
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
```

Is now:

```
var scroll = $('#table-container').offset().top;
```

Then I changed the statement to call the function:

```
$(window).scroll(moveScroll);
```

Is now:

```
$('#table-container').scroll(moveScroll);
```

Lastly I manually set the top of the fixed header to 130px to match the bottom of the topsection.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hvRZy/

**I still can't solve the border-collapse issue** though so if anyone has any ideas on that front that'd be amazing. Thanks!

**EDIT:** I've managed to solve the border issue with the following `CSS` (also added rounded corners):

```
table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
table tr th, table tr td {
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
}
table tr th:first-child, table tr td:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
table tr th {
    background: #c0c0c0;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    text-align: center;
}
table tr:first-child th:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 6px;
}
table tr:first-child th:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 6px;
}
table tfoot tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
}
table tfoot tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
}
```

One last fiddle!
http://jsfiddle.net/KfxQg/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery TH Float Plugin](http://rommelsantor.com/jquery/thfloat/). If you want to make `table th` to be fixed you can use it like this

```
$("#maintable").thfloat({
  attachment : "#maintable",
  noprint : false
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/urvfE/1/)

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using third party plugins if possible as I'd like to be able to maintain this myself, especially since the code I have is working reliably. Strangely that plugin seems to struggle with border-collapse as well, at least in the fiddle.