# Table header needs to remain fixed during scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, css-position

I have a table with a header and a body, and I want the table header to remain fixed while scrolling happens on the body.

The table is set up like so:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
            <th>Header 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
            <td>Data 3</td>
        </tr>

        ...more rows for data...

    </tbody>
```

The table is encapsulated with a  and has CSS like:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
height: 400px;
```

I need the table header to remain perfectly still but when I add position: fixed; to thead or to the individual th the header gets squished.

Whats the best approach for this?

Comment: I can recommend a cool resource on positioning - http://learnlayout.com/. 
In general, position:fixed is what i would go with, as Jason replied below.

Comment: since i wrote a plugin that does this, i can say that fixed positioning is a very important but a very small part of the equation

Comment: @cdub can you share some codes with me like how its working with html and script code

Answer (score 18, accepted):

i just updated a plugin that I wrote that does this exact thing:

http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/

it may be what you need

Comment: Hi, I have used your plugin for fixed header & it works perfectly. Same thing I want to do for first column to fixed when scroll horizontally. Do you have any suggestions for this that how can I achieve both fixed header & fixed first column when scroll vertically & horizontally. Hope you can get back to me with some solution as early as possible. Thanks in advance...

Comment: google it, there might be a plugin that locks the first column that works nicely with my plugin.  my plugin does not lock the first column and never will

Comment: @mkoryak hey sir can you share a small source code of scrolling table body with fix header,because i went to your link but there is no perfect example of that there is nohtml

Comment: no I cannot, that is a silly thing to ask.

Answer (score 1):

If you need your tables to contain any dynamic data so that you can't specify width, you'll have to use a JS/jQuery solution like the following:

[Table header to stay fixed at the top when user scrolls it out of view with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque)

If you know exactly what is going to be displayed though and don't mind making some tweaks/hacks, you can just make your `thead` `position:fixed`, then mess with the spacing until it looks good.

[Take a look at this jsFiddle to see what I mean.](http://jsfiddle.net/yXTD9/)

**EDIT: Here's an updated jsFiddle that's spaced a little better, because OP was too lazy to type in a few characters for himself and expects others to do everything for him.**

http://jsfiddle.net/yXTD9/1/

Comment: The JSFiddle is not what I meant, as your header does not match your data. Look at columns 2 and 3.

Comment: Did you mess with the code or just glance at the page and see if the work was done for you? Hell did you even read my post?

Comment: this problem cant be solved with pure css, if you want a generic solution.. see: http://jsfiddle.net/yXTD9/2/ and scroll to the bottom of the page. or http://jsfiddle.net/yXTD9/3/ :P