# HTML -- cannot get header to stay fixed in scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used the logic from the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque) to implement the fixed header that should stay while the rest of the table scrolls. I tried a few other plugins but none of them worked properly so I've almost given up at this point.

I used this code to re-size my table (they are usually HUGE) to fit the visible area:

```
   var buttonDist = jQuery("#resizableTable").position().top - jQuery("#tglTblScrollLock").position().top;
   document.getElementById('resizableTable').style.width = (visWidth) +'px';
   document.getElementById('resizableTable').style.height = (visHeight * 0.95) - buttonDist - menuOffset +'px';
   document.getElementById('resizableTable').style.display = 'block';
```

Then I did this (like in the link)

```
        var tableOffset = jQuery("#resizableTable").offset().top;
        var header = jQuery("#resizableTable > thead").clone();
        var fixedHeader = jQuery("#resizableTable").clone()

        fixedHeader.css({'position':'absolute', 'top': jQuery("#resizableTable").position().top, 'display':'none'});
        fixedHeader.attr("id",'fixedHeader');

        jQuery("#tab1").append(fixedHeader);
        jQuery('#fixedHeader > tbody').remove();
        jQuery('#fixedHeader > tfoot').remove();

        jQuery("#resizableTable > thead").bind("scroll", function() {
            var offset = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
            if (offset >= tableOffset && fixedHeader.is(":hidden")) {
                fixedHeader.show();
            }
            else if (offset < tableOffset) {
                fixedHeader.hide();
            }    
        });
```

Here's an issue. `jQuery("#resizableTable > thead").bind("scroll", function() {` is not working.  It's not even getting called -- if I replace the part to check for scrolling in `window` it works, but not with that. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you are actually scrolling the thead, you are probably scrolling elsewhere and thus since the thead element itself does not internally have overflow scroll going on...

Paste a jsFiddle and I'll verify that hunch.

Comment: Wait, then what would I be scrolling?  The table is the one I changed the width & the height of - and I tried changing `jQuery("#resizableTable > thead")` to `jQuery("#resizableTable")` and that didn't work either.

Comment: Without a jsFiddle to confirm, my guess is that what is actually scrolling is the body or the container parent of the table that has an overflow:scroll or overflow:auto.  Remember that with the scroll event it is going to fire on the element that is the "container" which is doing the scrolling, not on the things inside which you see moving.

Comment: Oh. I just started helping with web dev stuff at work like a week or two ago. I have no prior exp with this. There are two `<div>` elements within each other that has the table (and its clone) in them -- would the inner div be what you're referring to?

Comment: Ah, you were right. When I changed it so that it was looking at the div element it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Might want to comment here the element you changed it to, so I can add it to the answer, or edit your post to explain the element... you'd be surprised how much this shtuff comes up in google and the poor kid googling is like "WTF WAS THE ANSWER"

Comment: I had a `<div>` element that had the table in it -- it had class set to 'tab1'. So I just changed it to `jQuery("div").find('.tab1').bind("scroll", function() {`

Comment: k, you could probably do this to be way more performant and not find all the divs only to subset them down:

jQuery(".tab1").bind("scroll", function() {

Comment: Yeah, you're right. That worked as well. Hmm. Question.  `var offset = jQuery(this).scrollTop();` isn't doing what I thought it would -- it's way too small. My idea was if the table gets past the visible area of the scrolling area, show the cloned header. Otherwise, hide the clone.  Are scrollTop() for offset and offset().top the wrong stuff to use for that?

Comment: This should help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollTop