# Fix table heading on top during scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to fix table heading on top during Scroll.
It is a Bootstrap theme and i don't want to use any plugin.
I have tried with the below code. table heading fix is working with Scroll.

But it is leaving CSS when scrolling.

[image]

No custom CSS used from my side. only Bootstrap Stuff used.

**HTML**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped persist-area">
        <thead>
            <tr class="persist-header">
                <th>........
                </th>
                <th>........
                </th>
                <th>........
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>.....
            </tr>
            <tr>....
            </tr>
            <tr>....
            </tr>
        <tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
 function UpdateTableHeaders() {
                var el             = $('.persist-area');
                   offset         = el.offset();
                   scrollTop      = $(window).scrollTop();
                   floatingHeader = $(".floatingHeader");

               if ((scrollTop > offset.top) && (scrollTop < offset.top + el.height())) {
                   floatingHeader.css({
                    "visibility": "visible"
                   });

               } else {
                   floatingHeader.css({
                    "visibility": "hidden"
                   });      
               };

        }


        $(function() {
            var clonedHeaderRow;
            clonedHeaderRow = $(".persist-header");
            clonedHeaderRow
            .before(clonedHeaderRow.clone())
            .css({"width" : clonedHeaderRow.width()})
                .addClass("floatingHeader");

            if($(".persist-header").hasClass('floatingHeader')){
                $(".persist-header th").each(function() {
                    clonedHeaderRowTh = $(this);
                });
            }

            $(window).scroll(UpdateTableHeaders).trigger("scroll");

        });
```

Comment: No custom CSS used from my side. only Bootstrap Stuff used.

Comment: Did you try that? http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top

Comment: sorry its my mistake.. it is a table heading not a Navigation .. question is updated.

Comment: [Look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque)
It looks like exactly the same of what you are asking.