# html table first row (first <td>) freeze along with table header

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, html

Am using html table in my project.

I want to make my html table header and first row freeze. I know how to make header freeze. But am not able to fix first row freeze. Can any one help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: can you please share how did you make header fixed?

Comment: refer my answer.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030703/how-to-keep-header-row-fixed-while-scrolling-on-a-sortable-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *Revised with Snippets*

I would just put the featured/highlighted (first) row in the `thead` group and it will be fixed with your header row as well.

```html
<style>
  table { width:100%; }
  table thead { position:fixed; }
  table thead tr th { text-align: left; }
  table tbody { position:absolute; top:60px; }
</style>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Header</th></tr>
    <tr><td>Highlighted Row</td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr><td>Row 1</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Row 2</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Row 3</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Row 4</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Row 5</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Row 6</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Row 7</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Row 8</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Row 9</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Row 10</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think answer by @Darshak Shekhda is sufficient but still if you want more explanation you can refer [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dimomohit/rcxk5j4p/). You can use 
`{  position:absolute;
   overflow:scroll;
}` to achieve your design. You can use `:nth-child(rowNumber){
   position:absolute;
   overflow:scroll;
}`
to select desired row. Hope this helps.