# html table fixed header

Tags: html, css

I have Html table with  12 columuns and with 15 - 30 no of rows. I need to make header and subHeader as fixed while scrolling.

i tried with overflow-y:auto; and position:fixed but content is getting moving along with header.

http://jsfiddle.net/1nteger/9LouLesp/8/

```
#myTable {
  width: 100%;
}

#Header {
  /*position:fixed;*/
}

#SubHeader {
  /*position:fixed;*/
}

.content {
  /*overflow-y:scroll*/
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some HTML aswell, are you using the <Table> tag or are you creating your own table with divs?

Comment: Here, I found JSfFiddle with the nice example. https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/

Comment: this issue is probably resolved here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque

Comment: Ricky@ I am trying to make header fixed.. like this example http://www.fixedheadertable.com/.. without using jquery with simple css.. :(