# Freeze HTML table header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how do i freeze the first row ( thead ) in a HTML table? Is this via javascript or is there an html option to freeze the header row?  (so when you scroll down vertically you can always see it).

how do i freeze the first row ( thead ) in a HTML table? Is this via javascript or is there an html option to freeze the header row?  (so when you scroll down vertically you can always see it).

```js
    function sortTable(f,n){
        var rows = $('#mytable tbody  tr').get();

        rows.sort(function(a, b) {

            var A = getVal(a);
            var B = getVal(b);

            if(A < B) {
                return -1*f;
            }
            if(A > B) {
                return 1*f;
            }
            return 0;
        });

        function getVal(elm){
            var v = $(elm).children('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();
            if($.isNumeric(v)){
                v = parseInt(v,10);
            }
            return v;
        }

        $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
            $('#mytable').children('tbody').append(row);
        });
    }
    var f_errorStringOfCurrentDataSet = 1;
    var f_errorStringOfMatchedDataSet = 1;
    var f_testCaseNameOfCurrentDataSet = 1;
    var f_regexMatched = 1;
    $("#errorStringOfCurrentDataSet").click(function(){
        f_errorStringOfCurrentDataSet *= -1;
        var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
        sortTable(f_errorStringOfCurrentDataSet,n);
    });
    $("#errorStringOfMatchedDataSet").click(function(){
        f_errorStringOfMatchedDataSet *= -1;
        var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
        sortTable(f_errorStringOfMatchedDataSet,n);
    });
    $("#testCaseNameOfCurrentDataSet").click(function(){
        f_testCaseNameOfCurrentDataSet *= -1;
        var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
        sortTable(f_testCaseNameOfCurrentDataSet,n);
    });
    $("#regexMatched").click(function(){
        f_regexMatched *= -1;
        var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
        sortTable(f_regexMatched,n);
    });
```

```css
    table {
        padding: 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        margin-top: 20px;
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 90%;
    }

    td {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 5px;
  word-break: break-word;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #f2f2f2
    }

    th, td {
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: left;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>


<h2>Hello: </h2> 
<br>

<br>

<table border="1" id="mytable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th width="14%" id="testCaseNameOfCurrentDataSet">Testcasename</th>
  <th width="5%" id="regexMatched">Regex</th>
        <th width="19%" id="processedErrorStringGuided">Processed Error Current</th>
        <th width="19%" id="processedErrorStringReference">Processed Error Reference</th>
        <th width="5%">Link</th>
        <th width="19%" id="errorStringOfCurrentDataSet">Raw Error Current</th>
        <th width="19%" id="errorStringOfMatchedDataSet">Raw Error Reference</th>        
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
  <tr style="color: red">
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            <td>NO</td>
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
   <td> ABCD </td>
            <td> ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV </td>
            <td> ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            
        </tr>
  <tr style="color: red">
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            <td>NO</td>
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
   <td> ABCD </td>
            <td> ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV </td>
            <td> ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            
        </tr>
  <tr style="color: red">
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            <td>NO</td>
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
   <td> ABCD </td>
            <td> ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV </td>
            <td> ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            
        </tr>
  <tr style="color: red">
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            <td>NO</td>
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
   <td> ABCD </td>
            <td> ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV </td>
            <td> ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            
        </tr>
  <tr style="color: red">
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            <td>NO</td>
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
   <td> ABCD </td>
            <td> ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV </td>
            <td> ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            
        </tr>
  <tr style="color: red">
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            <td>NO</td>
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
   <td> ABCD </td>
            <td> ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV </td>
            <td> ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            
        </tr>
  <tr style="color: red">
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            <td>NO</td>
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
   <td> ABCD </td>
            <td> ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV </td>
            <td> ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            
        </tr>
  <tr style="color: red">
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            <td>NO</td>
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
   <td> ABCD </td>
            <td> ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV </td>
            <td> ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            
        </tr>
  <tr style="color: red">
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            <td>NO</td>
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
   <td> ABCD </td>
            <td> ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV </td>
            <td> ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            
        </tr>
  <tr style="color: red">
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            <td>NO</td>
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            <td>ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
   <td> ABCD </td>
            <td> ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV </td>
            <td> ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UVABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV ABCD EFDH IJKL MNOP QRST UV</td>
            
        </tr>

    </tbody>
   </table>
```

Comment: are you asking if you can keep a header position: fixed?

Comment: yes. the first row of the HTML table should always be visible when we scroll down vertically .

Comment: duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table header to stay fixed at the top when user scrolls it out of view with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque)

Answer (score 1):

Define the `thead` of the table. Assign `position:fixed` to that element and the relative height. 
Define the `tbody` with `position:absolute` and with the top starting at the end of the table header.

HTML:

```
<table id="table-1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Col1</th>
            <th>Col2</th>
            <th>Col3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
            <td>info</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
body { height: 1000px; }
thead { 
  position: fixed; 
  height: 20px;
}
tbody { 
  top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fj8wM/6916/