# Getting table columns to retain width when getting fixed to viewport (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html-table

My question is similar to [what was asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque) regarding keeping a table header fixed to the top of the viewport when scrolled over/past -- except I'm more concerned about the effect it has on the columns (`th`) within the table header.

In the comments on **Andrew Whitaker**'s answer, there are some interesting suggestions to using jQuery to "fetch" the current width of the table header's columns and setting the *fixed* table header's columns to those widths.

However, this seems like a lot of heavy lifting especially when I'm already rendering a table within a React application (avoiding jQuery within React). It's a long shot, but has anyone come up with a better implementation?

I suppose I can just fall back to doing what is being done in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1n23m69u/2/) with vanilla JS.

Small snippet of jQuery logic from fiddle^

```
var tableOffset = $("#table-1").offset().top;
var $header = $("#table-1 > thead");
var $fixedHeader = $("#header-fixed").append($header.clone());

$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    var offset = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (offset >= tableOffset && $fixedHeader.is(":hidden")) {
        $fixedHeader.show();

        $.each($header.find('tr > th'), function(ind,val){
          var original_width = $(val).width(); // get width value from each
          var original_padding = $(val).css("padding"); // get padding from each
          $($fixedHeader.find('tr > th')[ind])
          .width(original_width)
          .css("padding",original_padding);
        });
    }
    else if (offset < tableOffset) {
        $fixedHeader.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: So you need an efficient way (with React) to keep the table headers the same width when you resize the table/window?

Comment: @davidatthepark More or less. I only brought up React, since I am rendering the table with a component and trying to avoid any kind of DOM manipulation via jQuery, which is what was brought up as an option in that other question I linked.