# table column alignment mismatch with the table header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on html table with bootstrap css and want to make the table header fixed with scrollable content.

Below is my code demo:

https://plnkr.co/edit/uRJ6WFVWevksH3ip4kct?p=preview

In my the above plunker demo,you can notice that the header is fixed and the content is scolling but the **alignment of the column with the header is mismatched**.I have given the same width for the `<td>` as given the width for `<th>` but still facing the alignment issue. Please advice what changes to be done to make the column of the content and the header matches and the other **issue i noticed is some content of the first row is hidden back to the table header**. I tried to resolve using different ways in CSS by setting the width of the header and the `<td>` but unable to make it..

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
        .header-fixed {
            width: 100%
        }
        .table-fixed thead {
     }
.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
thead {
    position: fixed; 
}
 </style> 
 </head>
<body>

<div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="" style="width: 80%; margin: 0px auto">
                <table  class="table table-bordered header-fixed" style="border :1px">
                    <thead>
                    <tr style="background-color: #cdd0d6;">
                        <th style="width:10%;white-space: wrap;text-align: center;">ID</th> 
                        <th style="width:30%;white-space: nowrap;text-align: center;">Description</th>              
                        <th style="width:10%;white-space: wrap;text-align: center;">DoorNum</th>
                        <th style="width:10%;white-space: wrap;text-align: center;">First Name</th>
                        <th style="width:10%;white-space: wrap;text-align: center;">Num of ordered items</th>
                        <th style="width:30%;white-space: wrap;text-align: center;">Desc Comments</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody >

                   <tr>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center;">10</td>
                        <td style="width:30%;text-align: center; ">Item belongs to Navvy modal 2014WE belomgs to the user name JOE dispathched after one week of odered date</td>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center; ">798</td>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center; ">Joe</td>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center; ">4</td>
                        <td style="widtg:30%;text-align: center; ">Order dispatched</td>
                    </tr> 
                     <tr>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center;">20</td>
                        <td style="width:30%;text-align: center; "></td>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center; ">798</td>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center; ">Joe</td>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center; ">4</td>
                        <td style="widtg:30%;text-align: center; ">Order dispatched</td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center;">30</td>
                        <td style="width:30%;text-align: center; ">Item belongs to Navvy modal 2014WE belomgs to the user name JOE dispathched after one week of odered date</td>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center; "></td>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center; ">Joe</td>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center; ">4</td>
                        <td style="widtg:30%;text-align: center; ">Order dispatched</td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center;">40</td>
                        <td style="width:30%;text-align: center; ">Item belongs to Navvy modal 2014WE belomgs to the user name JOE dispathched after one week of odered date</td>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center; ">798</td>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center; ">Joe</td>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center; ">4</td>
                        <td style="widtg:30%;text-align: center; ">Order dispatched</td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center;">50</td>
                        <td style="width:30%;text-align: center; ">Item belongs to Navvy modal 2014WE belomgs to the user name JOE dispathched after one week of odered date</td>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center; ">798</td>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center; ">Joe</td>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center; ">4</td>
                        <td style="widtg:30%;text-align: center; ">Order dispatched</td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center;">60</td>
                        <td style="width:30%;text-align: center; ">Item belongs to Navvy modal 2014WE belomgs to the user name JOE dispathched after one week of odered date</td>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center; ">798</td>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center; ">Joe</td>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center; ">4</td>
                        <td style="widtg:30%;text-align: center; ">Order dispatched</td>
                    </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center;">70</td>
                        <td style="width:30%;text-align: center; ">Item belongs to Navvy modal 2014WE belomgs to the user name JOE dispathched after one week of odered date</td>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center; ">798</td>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center; ">Joe</td>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center; ">4</td>
                        <td style="widtg:30%;text-align: center; ">Order dispatched</td>
                    </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center;">8</td>
                        <td style="width:30%;text-align: center; ">Item belongs to Navvy modal 2014WE belomgs to the user name JOE dispathched after one week of odered date</td>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center; ">798</td>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center; ">Joe</td>
                        <td style="width:10%;text-align: center; ">4</td>
                        <td style="widtg:30%;text-align: center; ">Order dispatched</td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque/5859976#5859976)

Answer (score 1):

Set that div width `<div class="" style="width: 80%; margin: 0px auto">` to `100%`

That,

`<div class="" style="width: 100%; margin: 0px auto">`

Maybe this can solve your problem.

Comment: +1 , As mentioned the other issue is some of the content in the first row is hidden and the header and content column alignment is slightly mismatched..

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the table behaviour. If you set a width for `td` and `th` it will still increase if the content is wider. One possible 'fix' would be to set the table-layout to fixed (in css), this will result in all `td`s and `th`s to have the same width but this may not be desirable. For smaller screens you can perhaps consider a responsive table. There's a really cool one for the Foundation framework: https://zurb.com/playground/responsive-tables or for Twitter Bootstrap (I see you're using that): https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/no-more-tables-respsonsive-table