# displaying background of fixed header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to create a fixed table-header with the following code [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque), but with checkboxes and they don't display properly. 
It works on fiddle example but I'm using Symfony3 and Twig, so it's possible that's causing the problem.

[image: Screenshot of table-header, checkboxes appear twice for each column instead of once]

How can I solve this?

```js
permissionFixed: function() {
  $.fn.fixMe = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this),
        $t_fixed;

      function init() {

        $t_fixed = $this.clone();
        $t_fixed.find("tbody").remove().end().addClass("fixed").insertBefore($this);
        resizeFixed();
      }

      function resizeFixed() {
        $t_fixed.find("th").each(function(index) {
          $(this).css("width", $this.find("th").eq(index).outerWidth() + "px");
        });
      }

      function scrollFixed() {
        var offset = $(this).scrollTop(),
          tableOffsetTop = $this.offset().top,
          tableOffsetBottom = tableOffsetTop + $this.height() - $this.find("thead").height();
        if (offset < tableOffsetTop || offset > tableOffsetBottom)
          $t_fixed.hide();
        else if (offset >= tableOffsetTop && offset <= tableOffsetBottom && $t_fixed.is(":hidden"))
          $t_fixed.show();
      }
      $(window).resize(resizeFixed);
      $(window).scroll(scrollFixed);
      init();
    });
  };
}
```

```css
.fixed {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: auto;
  display: none;
  border: none;
}

.permissionsFixedTHead thead {
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 10;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<table class="permissionsFixedTHead table table-bordered permissions">
  <thead>
    {% if form_errors(form.permissions) %}
    <tr>
      <td class="has-error" colspan="7">{{ form_errors(form.permissions) }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endif %}
    <tr>
      <th>Section</th>
      <th>Route</th>
      {% for operation in operations %}
      <th>
        <label for="{{ operation }}CheckboxAll">
          <input type="checkbox" id="{{ operation }}CheckboxAll" data-method="{{ operation == 'update' ? 'put':'' }}"/> {{ operation|capitalize }}
        </label>
      </th>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for permission in permissions %} {% for route in permission.routes %}
    <tr>
      {% if loop.first %}
      <td rowspan="{{ permission.routes|length }}" style="vertical-align: middle;">{{ permission.section }}</td>
      {% endif %}
      <td>{{ route.name }}</td>
      {% for crud, operation in route.operations %}
      <td class="text-center">
        {% if operation is not empty %}
        <label class="checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-{{ crud }}"
 id="{{ "%s_%s_%s"|format(crud, operation.action, operation.id) }}"
 name="role[permissions][]"
 value="{{ operation.id }}" {{ operation.id in form.permissions.vars.value ? 'checked' : null }}
                                                               data-method="{{ operation.method }}">
        </label> {% endif %}
      </td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %} {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @RogerC edited question.

Comment: @RogerC edited.

Comment: Are you sure you provided the whole CSS? Is there some other stylesheet included in your document? Because I can't reproduce that behaviour with the checkboxes.

Comment: @RogerC there's only class="checkbox" and it's has `.checkbox {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}`

Comment: I can't reproduce it. I'm guessing some CSS is missing as the style I'm getting from the code you provided is different than your screenshot.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data for the table, please? There's also a syntax error in the JavaScript you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

We need to add z-index on .fixed css class.

```
.fixed {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: auto;
  display: none;
  border: none;
  z-index: 10000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simle way to fixed the header of table, when your table has a fixed width and fixed layout only css, like in this example:

> Note: if any cell must be larger as others use `colspan`

```css
table{
  width:550px;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
td{
  padding:8px
}
.container{
  height:162px;
  overflow:auto
}
```

```html
<table border=1>
    <tr>
      <td>Col1</td>
      <td>Col2</td>
      <td colspan=2>Col3</td>
      <td>Col4</td>
      <td>Col5</td>
      <td>Col6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="container">
<table border=1>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td colspan=2>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
       <td>info</td>
     </tr>
</table>
</div>
```