# Table Head not taking full width of page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello below you can see my table, however, it does not take the full width of the page, I believe it has something to do with my

```
 <div style={{ overflow: 'auto', height: '250px' }}>
```

However, I need the table headers to stay within the page and not be allowed to be scrolled down with the table body

Comment: If you don't need to support IE, you can use `position: sticky` 

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp    
https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution works perfectly in chrome. This doesn't work in IE.[Refer here for more solutions that work with Javascript and jQuery that works for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque)

```
    table thead tr th {
      position: -webkit-sticky; 
      position: sticky;
      background-color: white;
      z-index: 100;
      top:-1px;
    }
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

table thead tr th {
  background-color: white;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 100;
  top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
      <td>Francisco Chang</td>
      <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ernst Handel</td>
      <td>Roland Mendel</td>
      <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Island Trading</td>
      <td>Helen Bennett</td>
      <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
      <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
      <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
      <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
      <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```