# thead and tbody not aligning properly after making thead fixed and tbody scrollable

Tags: css

I want my table to have fixed thead and scrollable tbody.I applied the following CSS to it:

```
thead, tbody { 
   display: block; 
}
tbody {
    height: 383px;        
    overflow-y: auto;  
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

After applying above css, `thead` got fixed, and `tbody` scrollable. But the data of `thead` is not aligning with `tbody`. Even there is a lot of space left in the right hand side of the table, it means `tr` elements doesn't fill the entire space of their container.

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table header to stay fixed at the top when user scrolls it out of view with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: sticky` to freeze your `th` cells:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 2vh;
  height: 90vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: none;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: black;
  padding: 3px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
        <th>header</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
        <td>cell</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Using it, if i am doing scrolling, the tbody content is going behind the thead, and it's visible also..not looking good..

Comment: Easily fixed with a bit of styling.