# Horizontal scroll in table attached with position fixed

Tags: html, css, css-tables

A div with different tables that should all scroll horizontally while the first table must be attached to the top of the page fixed, so it is also visible when scrolling vertically.

Is there anyway to get this to work? Check out the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/1eu69ozm/8/

```css
.table-container {
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#firstTableWrapper {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
  <div id="firstTableWrapper">
    <table id="firstTable" class="tableClass">
      <tr class="trFirst">
        <th>
          <span>Make</span>
        </th>
        <td>Harley-Davidson</td>
        <td>BMW</td>
        <td>Honda</td>
        <td>Yamaha</td>
        <td>Ducati</td>
        <td>Kawasaki</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <table class="tableClass">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <span>Model</span>
      </th>
      <td>Street Glide</td>
      <td>R 1250 GS Adventure</td>
      <td>CBR600RR</td>
      <td>YZF-R6</td>
      <td>Panigale V2</td>
      <td>Ninja ZX-10R</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <span>Color</span>
      </th>
      <td>Black</td>
      <td>White</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>Blue</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td>Green</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Table header to stay fixed at the top when user scrolls it out of view with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out moments after this post

Just add max width and overflow-x, think I tried before but without max-width..

```
     #firstTableWrapper {
      position: fixed;
      max-width: 100%;
      overflow-x: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just as [Rafael Bento](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19035201/rafael-bento) said, use the `<thead></thead>` and `<tbody></tbody>` tags.
Your `max-width:100%;overflow-x:auto;overflow-y:hidden`. Best achieved if you use bootstrap 5 responsive table.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't split in two tables unless you have a fixed column width. Using a `thead` and `tbody`, and fixing the `thead` with `position: sticky` is the best way. That way, the width of a column can be calculated automatically keeping the data aligned.

```css
.table-container {
  height: 170px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: scroll;
  max-width: 400px;
}
.tableClass {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.tableClass thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: orange;
}
.tableClass tbody {
  height: 150px;
}
.tableClass th, .tableClass td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 2px 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-container">
  <table id="firstTable"  class="tableClass">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><span>Make</span></th>
        <td>Harley-Davidson</td><td>BMW</td><td>Honda</td><td>Yamaha</td><td>Ducati</td><td>Kawasaki</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th><span>Model</span></th><td>Street Glide</td><td>R 1250 GS Adventure</td><td>CBR600RR</td><td>YZF-R6</td><td>Panigale V2</td><td>Ninja ZX-10R</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><span>Color</span></th>
        <td>Black</td><td>White</td><td>Red</td><td>Blue</td><td>Red</td><td>Green</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><span>Year</span></th>
        <td>2022</td><td>2021</td><td>2019</td><td>2020</td><td>2021</td><td>2022</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><span>Year</span></th>
        <td>2022</td><td>2021</td><td>2019</td><td>2020</td><td>2021</td><td>2022</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><span>Year</span></th>
        <td>2022</td><td>2021</td><td>2019</td><td>2020</td><td>2021</td><td>2022</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><span>Year</span></th>
        <td>2022</td><td>2021</td><td>2019</td><td>2020</td><td>2021</td><td>2022</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><span>Year</span></th>
        <td>2022</td><td>2021</td><td>2019</td><td>2020</td><td>2021</td><td>2022</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>  
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, the reason I need two tables is because I simplified the question. What I really  working on is a much more complex table/site where I handle a lot of different type of data and for many reason need many tables. Here I use thead and tbody for each table.

Comment: Ok. But use sticky instead of fixed, that way the content dont go below it.