# Make the first column of a table always visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We want to implement a solution to make the first column of a table always visible, whenever the user scrolls to the right (the table will be super-wide sometimes), the first column's cells have to 'stick' to the left of a screen.
There is a non-functional restriction in a project which makes a 'DIV approach' not possible.

This is somewhat similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030043/html-table-headers-always-visible-at-top-of-window-when-viewing-a-large-table)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/sticky-elements/ check this out it's what you need ...

Comment: It is not, unfortunately. It has a vertical scrolling feature, not a horizontal one. I checked this already. Thanks though.

Comment: Convincing browsers to do this is going to be really hard. You could try doing a one-column table that doesn't scroll, and put the rest of the columns in a table floated (and scrollable) to its right.

Comment: How is it that jQuery is ok, but a 'div approach' is not?  Can you give more detail on this strange requirement so that we are not operating blindly trying to find a solution?  Do you meant that you are restricted to only using table elements and no other elements?  Only the original table, or are multiple tables acceptable?

Comment: In the world of non-func requirements you will get used to a 'strange requirements'. The main coding concern here is that DOM is already super complicated and dirty hence building substitutions with DIVs dynamically will break 10 more places of code. Building this statically will involve a custom control development or moving from grid view to a repeater (this is all ASP.NET driven, btw).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and have a look at this [jquery pluging](http://fixedheadertable.com/).

or, even better, use [DataTables](https://datatables.net) which supports [fixed columns](https://datatables.net/reference/api/fixedColumns()).
I've included the sample from [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/simple.html).

Run code snipped in **Full Page** to see how it works.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        300,
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         false,
        fixedColumns:   true
    } );
} );
```

```css
/* Ensure that the demo table scrolls */
    th, td { white-space: nowrap; }
    div.dataTables_wrapper {
        width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.2/css/fixedColumns.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.2/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="stripe row-border order-column" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>E-mail</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger</td>
                <td>Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
                <td>5421</td>
                <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett</td>
                <td>Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
                <td>8422</td>
                <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton</td>
                <td>Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
                <td>1562</td>
                <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric</td>
                <td>Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
                <td>6224</td>
                <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi</td>
                <td>Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
                <td>5407</td>
                <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle</td>
                <td>Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
                <td>4804</td>
                <td>b.williamson@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod</td>
                <td>Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
                <td>9608</td>
                <td>h.chandler@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona</td>
                <td>Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
                <td>6200</td>
                <td>r.davidson@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen</td>
                <td>Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
                <td>2360</td>
                <td>c.hurst@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya</td>
                <td>Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
                <td>1667</td>
                <td>s.frost@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena</td>
                <td>Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
                <td>3814</td>
                <td>j.gaines@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn</td>
                <td>Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
                <td>9497</td>
                <td>q.flynn@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde</td>
                <td>Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
                <td>6741</td>
                <td>c.marshall@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley</td>
                <td>Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
                <td>3597</td>
                <td>h.kennedy@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana</td>
                <td>Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
                <td>1965</td>
                <td>t.fitzpatrick@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael</td>
                <td>Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
                <td>1581</td>
                <td>m.silva@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul</td>
                <td>Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
                <td>3059</td>
                <td>p.byrd@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria</td>
                <td>Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
                <td>1721</td>
                <td>g.little@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley</td>
                <td>Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
                <td>2558</td>
                <td>b.greer@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai</td>
                <td>Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
                <td>2290</td>
                <td>d.rios@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette</td>
                <td>Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
                <td>1937</td>
                <td>j.caldwell@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri</td>
                <td>Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009/06/25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
                <td>6154</td>
                <td>y.berry@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar</td>
                <td>Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011/12/12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
                <td>8330</td>
                <td>c.vance@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris</td>
                <td>Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010/09/20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
                <td>3023</td>
                <td>d.wilder@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica</td>
                <td>Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
                <td>5797</td>
                <td>a.ramos@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin</td>
                <td>Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010/12/22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
                <td>8822</td>
                <td>g.joyce@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer</td>
                <td>Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
                <td>9239</td>
                <td>j.chang@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden</td>
                <td>Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
                <td>1314</td>
                <td>b.wagner@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fiona</td>
                <td>Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>2010/03/11</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
                <td>2947</td>
                <td>f.green@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shou</td>
                <td>Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>2011/08/14</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
                <td>8899</td>
                <td>s.itou@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michelle</td>
                <td>House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2011/06/02</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
                <td>2769</td>
                <td>m.house@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suki</td>
                <td>Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>2009/10/22</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
                <td>6832</td>
                <td>s.burks@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prescott</td>
                <td>Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/05/07</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
                <td>3606</td>
                <td>p.bartlett@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin</td>
                <td>Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2008/10/26</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
                <td>2860</td>
                <td>g.cortez@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Martena</td>
                <td>Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/03/09</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
                <td>8240</td>
                <td>m.mccray@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unity</td>
                <td>Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/12/09</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
                <td>5384</td>
                <td>u.butler@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howard</td>
                <td>Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/12/16</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
                <td>7031</td>
                <td>h.hatfield@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hope</td>
                <td>Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2010/02/12</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
                <td>6318</td>
                <td>h.fuentes@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vivian</td>
                <td>Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>2009/02/14</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
                <td>9422</td>
                <td>v.harrell@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Timothy</td>
                <td>Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2008/12/11</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
                <td>7580</td>
                <td>t.mooney@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jackson</td>
                <td>Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>2008/09/26</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
                <td>1042</td>
                <td>j.bradshaw@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Olivia</td>
                <td>Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2011/02/03</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
                <td>2120</td>
                <td>o.liang@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruno</td>
                <td>Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>2011/05/03</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
                <td>6222</td>
                <td>b.nash@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sakura</td>
                <td>Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2009/08/19</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
                <td>9383</td>
                <td>s.yamamoto@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thor</td>
                <td>Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2013/08/11</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
                <td>8327</td>
                <td>t.walton@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Finn</td>
                <td>Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/07/07</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
                <td>2927</td>
                <td>f.camacho@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Serge</td>
                <td>Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2012/04/09</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
                <td>8352</td>
                <td>s.baldwin@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zenaida</td>
                <td>Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2010/01/04</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
                <td>7439</td>
                <td>z.frank@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zorita</td>
                <td>Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>2012/06/01</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
                <td>4389</td>
                <td>z.serrano@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer</td>
                <td>Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2013/02/01</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
                <td>3431</td>
                <td>j.acosta@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cara</td>
                <td>Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/12/06</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
                <td>3990</td>
                <td>c.stevens@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hermione</td>
                <td>Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2011/03/21</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
                <td>1016</td>
                <td>h.butler@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lael</td>
                <td>Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2009/02/27</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
                <td>6733</td>
                <td>l.greer@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jonas</td>
                <td>Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2010/07/14</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
                <td>8196</td>
                <td>j.alexander@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shad</td>
                <td>Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/11/13</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
                <td>6373</td>
                <td>s.decker@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael</td>
                <td>Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
                <td>5384</td>
                <td>m.bruce@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna</td>
                <td>Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
                <td>4226</td>
                <td>d.snider@datatables.net</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: That plugin appears to be about the table *header*, which is nice but it doesn't seem to be what's being requested.

Comment: table headers can be horizontal :)

Comment: Exactly, the table already has horizontal headers defined and everything is coded to make them always visible. Now we'd like to have the same thing for the first column's cells.

Comment: @Pointy: if you have a look at the demo and set fixedColum ON you will see that the grid has the first column (and the header) frozen.

Comment: Ah OK - they need to improve their marketing materials :-) *edit* yes indeed that does seem to do it.  Pretty cool.

Comment: @Arthur P: as I told Pointy the demo allows you to freeze the first column.

Comment: @Pointy: agree. Good thing is they're still working on it and fixing bugs: https://github.com/golovko/Fixed-Header-Table

Comment: @LeftyX Thanks, I will check it out to see if it does what I exactly need.

Comment: @Arthur P: I've updated my answer.I've found out that DataTables can do that too, and Datatables is a great grid.

Answer (score 1):

make 2 tables: left and right.
height of TD you should set by script (height of TD of right table = height of TD of left table, or select the biggest and set to smaller TD).
during scroll, check scrollLeft and on some value make left table position fixed/absolute.

i think all plugins work like this.