# Keeping the row title and column title of a table visible while scrolling

Tags: javascript, html-table

I've got a large table, where the user typically needs to scroll the page to find data. This makes it difficult to track columns/rows once the headers are no longer visible. I'd like to keep the headers visible while scrolling.

I've managed to get the first row (column headers) to stay visible ([jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/AvaUU/27/)), but am at a loss to do the same for the first column.

PS: I don't need an iframe solution (with extra scrolls), but one similar to what I have, but for the first column.

EDIT: I've done it: [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/AvaUU/35/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030043/html-table-headers-always-visible-at-top-of-window-when-viewing-a-large-table

Comment: Not a duplicate. I need BOTH the first row and the first column to stay visible. I could't find an answer to this on stackoverflow.

Comment: There are a lot of working JS solutions out on the web. For example http://www.datatables.net – what you are searching for is a combination of the "FixedColumns" and the "FixedHeader" plug-ins (if using jQuery-datatables). BTW: your solution flickers heavy while scrolling.

Comment: Note that if you keep scrolling in your example the result flips from bottom of table back to top

Comment: @mrtsherman You're right, the code is not perfect...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those interested, I fixed the flickering and the flipping, and the result is now perfect (for me). ([jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/AvaUU/39/))

Answer (score 3):

Using JS seems to be a bit overkill for this solution. Working with tables can be a pain in the neck, but there's a CSS property called `position: fixed` which could be used for this purpose. I've put together a demo which isn't 100% perfect when it comes to lining things up, but it demonstrates how to use it for your application.

**DEMO:** http://wecodesign.com/demos/stackoverflow-7433377.htm

Comment: I will try your code, but I suppose it's working only with fixed sizes, margins, width, etc... although I'm not sure. I will give it a try. Thank you.