# HTML table headers always visible at top of window

Tags: html, css, html-table

Please refer to [HTML table headers always visible at top of window when viewing a large table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030043/html-table-headers-always-visible-at-top-of-window-when-viewing-a-large-table)

the solution that Craig McQueen provided work great for IE7 which is what I need currently. However, I tested with different browser, when I scroll down, the header flicking/flashing. How can I fix it?

Comment: Which browser isn't working and on what OS?

Comment: the fixed header in ff 8.0 is flicking.

Answer (score 8):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/raqJ2/2/

Tested it on FF, Chrome and IE7 and up. No jumpiness or flicker/flash. Check it out.

Basically involves moving the header row to a fixed position element, instead of manipulating its top every time.

**UPDATE**

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/raqJ2/8/

Added a small timed animation to scroll the header left/right to the desired location 500 ms after scroll ends. Check it out. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, there is no more flicker/flash. However, the fixed header isn't scrollable horizontally when I put more columns into it, like 30 columns. It is better to support auto width, since I use a database to populate the data into the table. And the current code may not allow  me to use fixed width.

Comment: See the fiddle in my update. Guess this is what you were looking for.

Comment: for some reason, the second update is no longer work in my application, the fixed header isn't fix anymore. With standalone test, when you scroll right, the header stay with the old table location, then the header moves to the right to match with the new table location. That is about 1 or 2 second lag. Could you fix that?

Comment: i gave a 500 ms delay before animating the header to scroll to the correct position. If you do not need the animation, you can change the `.animate(...)` to `.css(...)` and the delay will be gone.

Comment: Add this line below `fhold.hide()` and you won't get your table to "jump" when scrolling back to the top of it: `win.scrollTop(win.scrollTop() + ftr.height());`

Comment: In that fiddle, the header doesn't line up with the table contents if they are indented. This small edit changes that. http://jsfiddle.net/0v4ht65L/3/