# Make table row invisible but its contents visible

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm using IE7 and IE8. Is there anyway to have a completely invisible or transparent table row which has table data that is visible?

Comment: What do you mean by "transparent table row", since you're not talking about its contents? Transparent background? No borders?

Comment: what you describe is the default behaviour.

Comment: Allow me to clarify; transparent as in if it had a higher z index and absolute position it would show the lower z level objects behind it.  Lamest metaphor ever but, think like a window with stickers on it the table row being the window the table data being the stickers.

Comment: I am assuming you have a [sort of] long table and you want to fix the `<th>`s so when you scroll they remain visable.

Comment: yes i have a relativly long table well several nested to be more exact

Comment: If that is the case, see [HTML table headers always visible at top of window when viewing a large table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030043/html-table-headers-always-visible-at-top-of-window-when-viewing-a-large-table)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean just one transparent row? That can be achieved with CSS by assigning a specific class to the table data row:

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="invisible"></td>
        <td class="invisible"></td>
        <td class="invisible"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.invisible {
    border: 0;
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sK338/

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need to add border="0"?