# Fixed table header with horizontal scroll inside div element

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, html-table

I have table with horizontal scroll and I want to stick header like in following proof of concept [HTML table headers always visible at top of window when viewing a large table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030043/html-table-headers-always-visible-at-top-of-window-when-viewing-a-large-table/1041566#1041566)
but horizontal scroll doesn't work properly when table is placed inside other element. Header is fixed by a position property and it doesn't move with rest of the table. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: here is code: http://jsfiddle.net/mmacin/M35xT/ use both scroll's to find problem

Comment: I have found nice solution for this issue on author's github repository:
https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders/issues/1
--->
http://jsfiddle.net/LqZ2T/42/