# keep div visible while scrolling only if second div is in view

Tags: javascript, html, css, visible

I have the following (simplified) HTML code:

```
<div>
..stuff...
</div>
<div class="subtitle" id="charts-title">
    <h3>Charts for d/m/y</h3>
</div>
<div class="content" id="charts">
    ...various charts...
</div>
<div>
...more stuff...
</div>
```

So, #charts-title is not at the top of the page, nor #charts at the bottom, they are somewhere in the middle of the page. Now, when the user scrolls down, #charts-title goes out of the screen and then I'm seeing charts with no date information. I want to keep #charts-title visible only if #charts is in view.

Thanks for any help,
Hector.

Comment: You'll need JavaScript for that.

Comment: jQuery provides tool for that type of manipulation

Comment: You might want to look at [this similar problem with table heading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030043/html-table-headers-always-visible-at-top-of-window-when-viewing-a-large-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This made it:

```
<div>
..stuff...
</div>
<div class="subtitle" id="float-charts-title" style="display:none; position:fixed; top: 0; z-index:100; background-color:white">
    <h3>Charts for d/m/y</h3>
</div>
<div class="subtitle" id="charts-title">
    <h3>Charts for d/m/y</h3>
</div>
<div class="content" id="charts">
    ...various charts...
</div>
<div>
...more stuff...
</div>

<script>
  $(window).scroll(function(){
  var rectTitle = $("#charts-title")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  var rectCharts = $("#charts")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
  if (rectTitle.bottom < 0 && rectCharts.bottom > 0) {
    $("#float-charts-title").css("display", "block");
  } else {
    $("#float-charts-title").css("display", "none");
  }
});
</script>
```

Thanks for the help.