# table rows and cells are broken

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following styling and HTML, but when it displays, the table appears broken (all the table rows and cells are broken). I'm not sure why; how can I fix it?

the tbody need have this size: `height: calc(100vh - 130px);`

the red line defines the size of the table.

edit: my `tbody` need have scroll and the `thead` need be fixed.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zuxq2gr0/11/

```css
.col-lg-12 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: calc(100vh - 130px);
}

tbody > tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="col-lg-8 ">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <table class="table table-striped" aurelia-table="">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>test</th>
          <th>test</th>
          <th>test</th>
          <th>test</th>
          <th>test</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--  textarea -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="textarea"></label>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <compose view="./-box.html"></compose>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: From what i have understood.. are you trying to keep the header fixed ?

Comment: yeap, and aligned the cells

Comment: Sadly this is not possible just by specifying height to the `tbody` and `overflow-y`. It just wont work.. You might have to remove all the `display` you specified and try using a plugin which can keep the headers fixed.

Comment: I have updated my answer, it might help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove some style as per following code:

```css
table {
    width: 50%;
}

thead, tbody, tr, td, th {
    display: block;
}

thead th {
    height: 30px;
}

tbody {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: calc(100vh - 130px);
}

tbody td, thead th {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}

tr:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="col-lg-8 ">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <table class="table table-striped" aurelia-table="">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>test</th>
          <th>test</th>
          <th>test</th>
          <th>test</th>
          <th>test</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>test</td>
          <td>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <option value="" selected=""></option>
                <option value="-action"> Action</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" click.delegate=""></i>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <!--  textarea -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-12 control-label" for="textarea"></label>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <compose view="./-box.html"></compose>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mate, `overflow-y: scroll`  `height: calc(100vh - 130px)`  this wont work on `tbody`, anyway removing the `display` properties is a valid solution for alignment proplem.

Answer (score 5):

**To fix the broken cells**

You need to remove display:block from tbody and remove display:table from tr element.

```
.col-lg-12 {
  border:1px solid red;
}
tbody {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: calc(100vh - 130px);
    width: 100%;
}

tbody > tr {
  width: 100%;
}
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zuxq2gr0/15/

**Making a sticky header**

The sticky header depends on the browser support you need. 
Easiest way to do it would be with position: sticky, see at work in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zuxq2gr0/17/
That only works in modern browsers though, needs prefixes and doesn't work in either IE or Edge (refer to CanIUse: https://caniuse.com/#search=sticky). There might be good polyfills out there, but I haven't tried any.

You could use position: fixed, but then you need to know all your heights and so on. Refer to this codepen: https://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu

Other than that you'll probably need to use a javascript. There are quite a few tutorials out there that cover javascript sticky headers. I haven't tried them, but here's one from [Codedrops](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/01/09/sticky-table-headers-columns/). There are also some SO questions concerning this topic, e.g.:

[Table header to stay fixed at the top when user scrolls it out of view with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709390/table-header-to-stay-fixed-at-the-top-when-user-scrolls-it-out-of-view-with-jque)

[HTML table headers always visible at top of window when viewing a large table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030043/html-table-headers-always-visible-at-top-of-window-when-viewing-a-large-table?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: sorry but the tbody and the content in the rows need be aligned, still not

Comment: ah OK. I didn't get that from the original question. Maybe you can edit that? I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Hey there, I added some stuff concerning the sticky table header. I don't have a complete solution ready, but some resources to look at.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are wanting is the `tbody` to still be scrollable. You were on the right track with making it Block, but to maintain the width of the Row you'll need to make your `thead` block as well

```
tbody,thead {
    display:block;
}

tbody{
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: calc(100vh - 130px);

}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cukhfq3z/)

You'll notice the Thead columns are not in line, the only way I know to fix this is via JS or styling each column width with CSS.

Here a link to another stack article:

[HTML table with 100% width, with vertical scroll inside tbody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067294/html-table-with-100-width-with-vertical-scroll-inside-tbody)

Answer (score 1):

just remove  `<thead>` and  `<tbody>` it will work here is the demo link
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/AdityaSrivastava/zuxq2gr0/18/)

Comment: This is Not a solution. Read the `CSS`. Its because the styles are wrong not because of `<thead>` or `<tbody>`

Comment: and just see the demo and then say

Comment: Dude, removing the standard html tags gives you a solution..?? Seriously?  I am guessing you don't know CSS for that matter

Comment: just see the demo i have changed the css with it